# Inverse if statement

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a question about Objective C

I want an inverted if statement. Like: `if (!example.hidden == YES) {`

Here's my code:

```
if ((randomBallTouch.x>_randomColorBall.center.x-(_randomColorBall.frame.size.width)/2) &&
    (randomBallTouch.x<_randomColorBall.center.x+(_randomColorBall.frame.size.width)/2) &&
    (randomBallTouch.y>_randomColorBall.center.y-(_randomColorBall.frame.size.height)/2) &&
    (randomBallTouch.y<_randomColorBall.center.y+(_randomColorBall.frame.size.height)/2)) {
    _randomColorBall.center = CGPointMake(randomBallTouch.x, randomBallTouch.y);

    if (_randomColorBall.hidden == NO) {
        _redBall.center = CGPointMake(_redBall.center.x, _redBall.center.y - 200);
    }
}
```

But when i do: `if(!(randomBallTouch.x>_randomColorBall.center.x))` etc. It does not work.

And I can't do else because that will bug with the other two if statements.

Any help?? I am using  Xcode 5.1.

Comment: http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html

Comment: (First off, you should somehow take advantage of formatting (as @rmaddy demonstrates) to clarify complex logic.  If simple formatting of a single statement doesn't clarify it enough, consider creating BOOL temps for the subexpressions and using the temps in your `if`.)

Comment: (And there is an old saying with regard to punctuation in English writing: "When in doubt, leave it out."  The equivalent saying with regard to parens in programming is "When in doubt, put them in.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just add an `!` at the beginning to invert the condition. You need to wrap the whole expression in a set of parentheses first.

If you have:

```
if (a && b) {
```

then the inversion is:

```
if (!(a && b)) {
```

You didn't add those parentheses.

Comment: Or apply DeMorgan's theorem (I think that's the formal name) and turn it into `if(!a || !b)`  Kind of depends on the actual conditions which is clearer.

Comment: @David I didn't use DeMorgan's Law (I think it's a law, not theorem) because I was generalizing. The OP's condition is a bit complicated so simply using `!()` around the original is far less error prone.

Comment: agreed, was just pointing out that at least sometimes it's possible to simplify the logic by applying DeMorgan, particularly when it's a lot of comparisons.  The good news is that modern compilers are actually pretty good at that kind of optimization anyway, so just use what gives the cleanest interpretation of the actual condition.

Comment: Wauw! Thanks everyone for responding so fast! Sorry i am just 14 years old so i'm a little bit noob to Xcode and Objective-C...

And i am not english... but dutch. So sorry for any grammar mistakes ;)

But i want to thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, just replace your if with this one.

```
if(!((randomBallTouch.x > (_randomColorBall.center.x-(_randomColorBall.frame.size.width)/2)) &&    (randomBallTouch.x < (_randomColorBall.center.x+(_randomColorBall.frame.size.width)/2)) &&     (randomBallTouch.y > (_randomColorBall.center.y-(_randomColorBall.frame.size.height)/2)) &&(randomBallTouch.y < (_randomColorBall.center.y+(_randomColorBall.frame.size.height)/2)))) {
```

You are missing a lot of parenthesis to make your statement a valid boolean.

Comment: You sure? Moved it into Xcode to show closing parenthesis and it matched up.

Comment: Oh, I see what you did. You added an extra set of parens to each expression. Given that you do have the right number. BTW - those aren't needed.